# How can I connect to a remote computer and output the specs of that computer using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Basically I want to connect to a remote computer by using its IP address. When connected I want to display the remote computer's specs and info (like msinfo32) on my computer. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a server-client modal where your client machine would connect to the remote machine.

[TCP Listenter(For writing the server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[TCP Client(For writing the client)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Once you have created your server and client, you would need to look into

[Windows Management Instrumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394587(v=vs.85).aspx)

To query that computers(the server's) hardware specs.